# comments editing bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

After a comment has been created or edited, clicking <kbd>edit</kbd> on it does nothing, editor is not shown. Also `delete` button (X-mark) doesn't show anymore when hovering comment. Reloading page helps overcoming the issue until next comment edit.

You can test it right here:

- Add a comment
- Try clicking `edit` button for any comment (without page reloading!)

Comment: you are right. Atleast I was able to reproduce what you said. When I refreshed your question, I could edit or delete the comment.

Comment: Good catch! happened to me as well but I assumed it was one time glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, that was broken. Fixed now, thanks!